# Science fiction short story - limited war where last surviving soldier is immune from all laws

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, warfare

Looking for a science fiction short story, probably published in 1960's or 1970's.  War has been formalized to a battle in a valley sized arena between two armies that is fought until only one soldier is left.  That solder is called a "Winner" and he is immune from all laws for the rest of his life. The wars are televised. Final scene is the "Winner" breaking into the house of a big fan of watching the wars and walking up the stairs to where his daughter is... anyone remember it?

Answer (score 13):

The Survivor, by Walter F. Moudy. 1965. The story is posted on this page:

http://like-the-hunger-games.blogspot.com/2011/12/books-like-hunger-games-survivor.html

Comment: Nicely done. That's the story. It's a beast! (I told you someone would find it!)