# Short story I read in a book of short stories in 1986ish

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

If I remember correctly, the story starts out with a young boy and his mother in a check out line at a store. A man comes into the store and grabs a bunch of stuff and walks out without paying for it. The young boy asks his mother why he was able to do this, she explains to him that the man won a great victory for his country and could take anything he wanted for the rest of his life.

The young boy wanted very much to be just like the man, when the boy grew up he was in a squad that fought for his country when there was conflict. Instead of war each country had a squad of fighters and the victor would decide the outcome of the conflict. The young man fought and won the conflict by hiding behind one of his dead squad mates in a foxhole/bunker. In the end he realized what war cost, and didn't envy the man from the store any longer.

I thought it was an Isaac Asimov story but still can't find it.

Comment: Perhaps "The Survivor" by Walter F. Moudy? See if this old question and answer matches: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103952/in-search-of-story-survivor-of-war-game-can-do-no-wrong You can read the whole story here: https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v39n05_1965-05#page/n77/mode/1up Is that the one?

Comment: I just finished reading the story.I don't believe it is the one i am looking for. there were some similarities in the story though.  then again it was a long time ago.I was thinking it was more focused on the character and how foolish he was as a young boy wanting to be like the war hero he saw all that time ago.thank you

Comment: wow i want to thank you all for helping me find this story. its been eluding me for decades.heck i even forgot the the very end part ,where he goes upstairs.